# TypeScript: Get cookie located on any path

Tags: javascript, typescript, cookies

I'd like to get a cookie localted on any path. Currently, I'm getting cookies value using this code:

```
export function getCookie(name) {
  let match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^;]+)'));
  return match ? match[1] : undefined;
}
```

I don't quite figure out how this code is looking up on cookies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`document.cookie` is a semicolon seperated string of cookies. For example:

```
cookie_foo=hello;cookie_bar=world;
```

Say you want the cookie `cookie_foo`. You want *everything* after `cookie_foo=` up until a `;`.

So to go through the regex:

```
cookie_foo                        <-- match cookie_foo
=                                 <-- match =
(                                 <-- start capture group
  [^;]+                           <-- match one or more characters that are NOT ;
)                                 <-- close capture group
```

This regex will match cookie, and capture the cookie contents in a capture group (the one you access in `match[1]`).